# differentiating an integral using Leibniz integral rule

Tags: derivatives

Was my attempt to solve this correct?
$$\frac {\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^{\infty}r^2e^{-2ar-2br^2}dr=-2\int_0^{\infty}r^3e^{-2ar-2br^2}dr$$

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: @MMM Thanks a lot.